# ImportError: No module named models, bokeh wakari

Tags: anaconda, bokeh

I am trying to implement the Bokeh library into my notebook on Wakari, Bokeh is installed however I am get the following error msg:

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-071dca5015d2> in <module>()
      3 from bokeh.sampledata import us_counties, unemployment
      4 from bokeh.plotting import *
----> 5 from bokeh.models import HoverTool
      6 
      7 county_xs=[

ImportError: No module named models
```

The code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from bokeh.sampledata import us_counties, unemployment
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated the bokeh package and this seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, `bokeh.models` appeared somewhere around Bokeh 0.7 (version 0.8.1 was just released).